# Reference to existing parameter in prepared statement on upsert

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I'm inserting or updating a row into Sqlite database with Go `database/sql` package. I have a lot of columns to update (about 16 columns of one item). To use `UPSERT` I need to duplicate all `?` and data fields parameters of the statement, so the total numbers of statement parameters is about 32:

```golang
// Save item to database using transaction
func (item *Item) Save(tx *sql.Tx) error {
  stmt, err := tx.Prepare(`INSERT INTO "items" (
    id, data1, data2, ..., dataN
  ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT(id)
  DO UPDATE SET data1 = ?, data2 = ?, ..., dataN = ?`) // set same values as insert
  // skip checking errors, defer close(), etc
  _, err := stmt.Exec(item.id,
                      item.data1, item.data2, /*...*/ item.dataN,
                      item.data1, item.data2, /*...*/ item.dataN) // duplicates
}
```

Is it possible to avoid duplicating and reference same parameters from `INSERT` and `DO UPDATE`?

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite, you can use pseudo-table `excluded` in the `DO UPDATE` clause to refer to the values that would have been otherwise inserted:

```
INSERT INTO "items" (id, data1, data2, data3)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) 
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET 
    data1 = excluded.data1, 
    data2 = excluded.data2,
    data3 = excluded.data3
```